# How to print a variable from a derived class?

Tags: python, python-2.x, super, derived

I know there are similar questions on this topics but none of them seem to apply to my case
Why would the following code print None and not True?
Thanks

```
class A(object):
    flag = None

    @classmethod
    def set_flag(cls):
        cls.flag = True

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def print_super_flag(cls):
        print cls.__bases__[0].flag  # This prints None
        print super(B, cls).flag   # This also

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.set_flag()
    b.print_super_flag()
```

Answer (score 1):

This call:

```
b.set_flag()
```

You defined `set_flag` as:

```
@classmethod
def set_flag(cls):
    cls.flag = True
```

So when `b` calls `set_flag`, `cls` is `B` - so it sets `B.flag`, not `A.flag`.  Then when you go to print `A.flag`, it is `None` because you never touched it.  So your issue is not at all in `print_super_flag` - you access `A.flag` correctly there.  Twice.

If instead you defined `set_flag` as:

```
class A(object):
     flag = None
     @classmethod
     def set_flag(cls):
         A.flag = True
```

Your code prints out `True` (twice), because `set_flag` now sets `A.flag` in derived classes.  Of course at this point your method being a `classmethod` is moot, but that's a function of how you expect the method to perform; when you call a `classmethod` from a derived class, `cls` is *that derived class*, not the parent class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer roippi. So, my question is, how can I access A.flag from B?

Comment: It's not a question of accessing `A.flag` from B - you're already doing that correctly (twice) in `print_super_flag`.  The issue is how you've written `set_flag`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this slightly extended version to see what's going on:

```
class A(object):
    flag = None

    @classmethod
    def set_flag(cls):
        cls.flag = True

class B(A):

    @classmethod
    def print_super_flag(cls):
        print cls.__bases__[0].flag  # This prints None
        print super(B, cls).flag   # This also

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = B()
    b.set_flag()
    print b.flag

    b2 = B()
    print b2.flag

    a = A()
    print a.flag
```

Prints:

```
True # because you set b.flag
True # because b.flag and b2.flag refer to the same class variable, B.flag
None # because B.flag and A.flag are NOT the same class variable
```

Basically, the child class (`B`) has its own copy of the `flag` class variable, rather than sharing it with the parent class (`A`).

More details [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables), assuming you're using Python 2.7-ish.

Comment: Actually yes, b.flag prints True. And "print cls.flag" also prints True withon "print_super_flag"... I'm confused, why wouldn't it work with super? I guess I'm confusing classes with objects...

Comment: In either case, `b.set_flag()` is equivalent to `B.set_flag(B)`, so even though the method that actually gets called is `A.set_flag(B)`, it's still `B.flag`, not `A.flag`, that is set to `True`.

Comment: @qwer0rewq, you're not confusing classes with objects, it's an issue of delineating the behavior of the parent class from the child class. The first argument (`cls`) of a class method refers to the class of the object through which the method is invoked (e.g. `B` for `b.set_flag`), which is **not necessarily the same class** as the one in which the method was created (e.g. `A`).

Answer (score 0):

If you only want there to only one flag attribute that's part of the base class, you need to change the `set_flag()` method to:

```
class A(object):
    flag = None

    @classmethod
    def set_flag(cls):
        A.flag = True
```

Since the revised method doesn't reference its `cls` argument, you could just make it `staticmethod` and remove the argument, although that's not extremely important. Regardless, by hardcoding the base class, you ensure which `flag` attribute is being set, otherwise another flag attribute will be created as part of `cls` argument, which is the class the call was made through.

Since only one class attribute exists, its value will be printed.